# How to scroll in page having long list using protractor?

Tags: protractor

I am using below function to scroll. It is working in all webpages but one. Webpage having long list it is not working. Please suggest alternative way

```js
function Common() {
    this.scrollPage = function (element) {
        browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
               .then(function () {
               })
    }
}
```

Comment: What failure are you receiving?

Comment: it is not scrolling page, no error thrown

Comment: left side of page i need to scroll in below screenshot

Comment: `scrollIntoView()` attempts to scroll a particular element into the viewport for the browser driver. If the element is larger than size of the viewport (visible section of browser window) it will not be able to scroll the whole element into view. Is that the case for you?

Comment: @Priya Add some html or error log to give a better view on the issue.

Comment: @DubinDev : Meeting name is long, MAy be that is causing error. I will try checking it

Comment: @DubinDev : I tried with smaller element also but still it is not working :-(

Comment: @Priya could you clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve? Are to trying to scroll to a particular element so you can take a screenshot of that element? Are you trying to just scroll to the bottom?

Comment: @DublinDev : I have long list of meetings. every time I create meeting it appends at the bottom of the list. So i need to scroll down to click on the meeting. I am still stuck, any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ok so you are trying to click on a meeting at the bottom of a list and it is not working. Can you update your question with the error message you are receiving? Maybe a screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

A similar code to what you've tried worked for me. Try with this:

```
return browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', element.getWebElement());
```

Comment: @Joaquic Casco: No luck :-(